# How do I replace my "base system shell" with IPython?

Tags: shell, python

I'd like to replace bash with IPython on my system, so that even files like .profile are in Python rather than shell script.

I have some confusion on the topic, even though asking a few questions on the matter. Here are the questions I have asked previously:

1) [How can I replace bash with Python?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176091/how-can-i-replace-bash-with-python)

From the answer to that question, I learned how to automatically replace bash with IPython *after* log in (note that it still uses .profile written in shell script).

2) [.profile is written in shell script — can I instead make my system understand that I want it to execute a Python script instead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248477/profile-is-written-in-shell-script-can-i-instead-make-my-system-understand-th)

From the answer to that question, I learned that .profile file is "sourced" rather than "executed" -- that is, the lines in .profile are run one by one, as if one were typing them into the shell.

So, my question now is: **how do I get my base system shell to be IPython, so that it can source .profile files with IPython magics/Python written inside them?** For example, I'd like to write my .profile file using IPython magics/Python.

Comment: iPython is not a shell, it is a Python interpreter / interactive environment.  There is no reasonable way to do what you are asking.  You can have your shell `profile` or `rc` file automatically start iPython for you, but that will not make it your shell; it will just be a program that your shell starts for you.

Comment: @DopeGhoti see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/209562/3486684

Comment: There is the fledgeling `pysh` shell which can be found at https://github.com/yunabe/pysh which may do what you are looking for.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Did you also read the answer I linked to?

Comment: I did.  It does a very good job of explaining that Python can in fact _do_ nearly every thing a shell _does_, but that does not negate the fact that Python is a scripting language and not a bona fide shell.  I would not be shocked to see some Pythonic flavor of `csh` or `tcsh` sometime down the line, but that day is not today.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Makes sense -- but what about IPython (rather than Python) as the "bona fide" shell, [since IPython is very shell like](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/shell.html?highlight=ipython%20shell)? By the way, I am sorry if these questions are stupid, since if it's not obvious yet, I am a total newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in using Python as a shell language and command prompt, you should look into [xonsh](https://xon.sh/). It is a Python based shell where you can write scripts in Python.

Comment: A great answer, can't understand why it was downvoted

Comment: @Krackout Because it doesn't attempt to answer the question. It may be an interesting tidbit, but it's only tangentially related to the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I disagree, xonsh does exactly that; it's Python plus shell syntax, able to replace bash.

Comment: @Krackout It may be so, but this is not an answer as it does not say anything other than "try this out". It's akin to a comment. In fact, there is already a _comment_ suggesting `pysh`. This is therefore on par with that comment, in its current form.  Feel free to expand on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have Python launched as your default shell by the `login(1)` process, you can change your shell in the `/etc/passwd` file using the command:

`usermod -s /usr/bin/python yourusername`

The`.profile` script will still not be executed. This filename/location is hardcoded into `bash(1)`. If you really want this, you could set up a shebang (#!) script that is interpreted by python and make this your user shell. You can then enter interactive mode from the script using `code.interact()`.

This won't work very well though (if at all). Python's interactive mode doesn't perform most of the functions of a shell (e.g. job control) and `os.system` won't help, as your system shell is now Python.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! One thing that remains unclear to me is whether you mean "IPython" when you refer to "Python"?

Comment: This isn't recommended, unless you also update `/etc/shells`. (Assuming things have changed recently or configured specially...) if your login shell is not listed in `/etc/shells`, you won't be able to login.